# React Native <Image> component's loadingIndicatorSource prop doesn't work?

Tags: image, react-native

I'm trying to get a simple loading gif showing while images download.

```js
<Image
  style={{height: 100, width:100}}
  loadingIndicatorSource={require('../assets/images/progress.gif')} //  does nothing.
  source={source}
/>
```

I know the asset works. If I put it in the `source` prop it displays perfectly.
However, when I use it in `loadingIndicatorSource` it doesn't show on iOS or Android.

The [documentation gives no special instructions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#loadingindicatorsource).

How can I get this prop to work?